# Official Microsoft NuGet Source

Tags: nuget-package, linqpad, nuget-spec

I would like to filter and search through the Microsoft released NuGet packages as a source but I cannot seem to find a way to only start with the Microsoft packages with the NuGet API; does anyone know the syntax or a URL to such a hive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So MS actually provides the answer in the settings of VS 2013: https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/curated-feeds/microsoftdotnet/

Works great in any application that utilises the NuGet API; LINQPad included!